# Select an sql field and don't show an specific word of the selection

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

When this query returns me the "Center" register, there is a word at all the fields with the same name that i don't want to display. I could make it via PHP but I need to use it on the db.

Basics I know, but i haven't done sql for a long time

```
SELECT
o.id_order,
o.reference AS Ref,
c.firstname AS Name,
c.lastname AS Last Name,
pl.`name` AS Center,
od.product_name AS Product,
od.product_quantity AS Quant,
ROUND(od.product_price * 1.21,2) AS Price,
o.date_add AS `Date`
FROM ps_orders AS o
INNER JOIN ps_order_detail AS od ON od.id_order = o.id_order
INNER JOIN ps_customer AS c ON c.id_customer = o.id_customer
INNER JOIN ps_product_lang AS pl ON pl.id_product = od.product_id
WHERE pl.id_lang = 1
ORDER BY od.id_order_detail DESC
```

When this returns me Center data, all fields have the preposition "The" in front, returning something like:

```
Center 
The Odoo Team Center
The Dev house
```

Then I need to show something like

```
Center 
Odoo Team Center
Dev house
```

Comment: what is your actual question ?

Comment: what word ? We cant run your query because we dont have your database. you need to tell us more

Comment: Mind giving an example data set?  having problems determining what you want

Comment: Is this SQL Server or MySQL?  The backticks  around `pl.name` will throw syntax errors in TSQL

Comment: The word is "the", is in mysql not sql-server, sorry my bad, andI think I can use a substring to do that, im gonna try!

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for but if i understand you correctly you can filter out a 'Centre' in your where clause. i.e. Where pl.`name` != 'MyCentre' or if you have many of them , you can say where pl.`name` not in ('mycentre1' , 'mycentre2'). Also you can use like keyword if you have just a part name you want to filter.

Comment: I update the description, is it now clearer?

Comment: Ah yes I understand you now , yes a substring would work as you said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `REPLACE`:

```
    SELECT
    o.id_order,
    o.reference AS Ref,
    c.firstname AS Name,
    c.lastname AS Last Name,
    REPLACE(pl.`name`,"The ","") AS Center,
    od.product_name AS Product,
    od.product_quantity AS Quant,
    ROUND(od.product_price * 1.21,2) AS Price,
    o.date_add AS `Date`
    FROM ps_orders AS o
    INNER JOIN ps_order_detail AS od ON od.id_order = o.id_order
    INNER JOIN ps_customer AS c ON c.id_customer = o.id_customer
    INNER JOIN ps_product_lang AS pl ON pl.id_product = od.product_id
    WHERE pl.id_lang = 1
    ORDER BY od.id_order_detail DESC
```

> **Documentation:** https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replace.html
>
> **Demo:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a5640/91

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work if you always wants to remove the first four chars:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(center, 4, LENGTH(center)-3) FROM YOURTABLE;
```